# Can't hover the child menu while creating css menu

Tags: css, menu

I am trying to create simple css menu with the following structure:

```
<section id="navigation-bar" class="container">
    <nav class="pull-left">
        <ul class="multiColumnMenu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <div class="column-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li> Sub menu 1 </li>
                        <li> Sub menu 2 </li>
                        <li> Sub menu 3 </li>
                        <li> Sub menu 4 </li>
                        <li> Sub menu 5 </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                          
            </li>
        ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

I trigger the menu with this css

```
.multiColumnMenu > li:hover  .column-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

The menu shows up but I can't hover over it. When I hover over it, it goes away.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pBrsF/)

Comment: where's the demo ? :)

Comment: there isn't demo link

Comment: @RaphaelDDL, I need to learn the mistake I did too.

Comment: Remove the `margin-top:8px;` and it will work. The `column-menu` needs to be near the li so these 8px gap makes the mouse go out of your `li` there fore the :hover state is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `margin-top` inside `.column-menu` causing it to disappear before you can hover over (due to the physical gap between the elements, the `:hover` state is lost) - remove that and it works fine.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pBrsF/2/)

Comment: Great, what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: If you want the gap add an 8px margin to the bottom of the anchor tag in the top menu to get the same effect without losing the hover state...

Answer (score 0):

THe quick and easy fix, but I dont think this is exactly how you want it to be done is to take your margin-top: 8px completely off. That will make your dropdown work. See code below

```
 .column-menu {
display: none;
left: 5px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
color: #7B0000;
background: rgb(252, 252, 252);
border: 1px #ccc solid;
border-bottom: 3px #ccc solid;
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
  }
```